# cross-origin url issue with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am having issues loading the ajax files, due to the path, when the url doesn't have 'www' in it.

so here is an example ajax code:

```
$('#show_helper').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: start_loader(),
        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'http://example.com/ajax/show-helper.php',
        data : 'x=1',
        success : function() {
            window.location.reload();
            end_loader();
        }
    }); 
});
```

So this works fine at www.mydomain.com, but if I am at http://example.com I get this error:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://example.com/ajax/show-helper.php. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

So how do I fix this? I tried changing the url path to //example.com... in the ajax code, but that didn't work.

Comment: Assuming your script and PHP resource are actually on the same host (it's difficult to tell with your mixed *mydomain.com* and *example.com* examples), simply use the path only, eg `url: '/ajax/show-helper.php'`

Answer (score 0):

ok, it would appear just changing the urls to e.g. /ajax/show-helper.php has solved the issue

Answer (score -1):

if you are sure to cross domain access this url,you can use jsonp

```
$.ajax({
type : "get",
async:false,
url : "http://example.com/ajax/show-helper.php",
dataType : "jsonp",
jsonp: "callbackparam",
jsonpCallback:"success_jsonpCallback",
success : function(json){
    window.location.reload();
    end_loader();
}
});
```

Otherwise,you can set a <base> tag in the <head>,then you can use the url "ajax/show-helper.phh"